# differnce between service factory vs component factory in OSGI

Tags: java, osgi

Can anybody please tell me the difference between component factory and service factory in **OSGI**. I searched a lot in Google but couldn't find the clear explanation of difference between service factory and component factory.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr: You almost certainly don't want to use ComponentFactory, so I recommend ignoring it.

Before I explain service factory, it's important to understand that **most** services in OSGi are conceptually singletons. When you register a service, you put a single Java object into the registry, and that object must implement the interface that it has been registered under. When clients lookup your service (using its interface) they all get that same object.

With service factories, you instead register a factory that creates objects implementing the interface. OSGi uses this factory to create a new instance *per consuming bundle*. This is useful because you can now provide each consuming bundle a slightly different object. For example if you are implementing a Logging service, using a service factory lets you keep track of which bundle is calling into the log.

However, service factory is completely transparent to the consumer. It just uses the service in the normal way. This is great, but sometimes the consumer needs programmatic control, i.e. the consumer decides exactly when a service object should be created and when it should be destroyed. This is NOT available with service factories.

Component factories were an early attempt to provide this programmatic control. I consider them obsolete. They were not easy to use because you had to couple both your provider and consumer to the Declarative Services API.

Nowadays you should use prototype-scoped services, that were introduced in OSGi Release 6. I blogged about these [here](http://njbartlett.name/2015/08/17/osgir6-declarative-services.html#prototype-scope-services)

Comment: you mean to say that Component factories were an early attempt to provide this programmatic control. Is that acheived via component factory or still an open? The problem is we are not using the latest osgi release. So we couldn't use scope mentioned in OSGi Release 6

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you rephrase please? Also are you really sure that you need programmatic control by the consumer over service objects? It's rarely needed in practice.

Comment: My requirement is to create component factories for the components. The question i have asked you is from the answer you have posted. ie) is the programmatic control is acheieved through component factory? One more thing while writing a component factory (factory="xxxx") i am using '@service' with '@component'. What is the need of @serivce in the factory implementation?